# Can not able to navigate to child screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabbar

My initialRouteName is **loginScreen**.

After signin Second screen came with **BottamTabNavigation**. BottomTab contain 4 screens and one of the screen named **GroupScreen** go to **TopTabScren**. I am not able to navigate To this screen.

The flow is --> loginScreen --> BottomTabScreen --> TopTabScreen.

I am not able to navigate to TopTabScreen. It gives error

> "*undefined is not an
>   object(evaluating'this.props.navigation.navigate'* ".

TopTabScreen leades to further 4 Screens

But when I set InitailRoutName= "TobTabScreen" then all the four screen work with that.

For navigation screens i am using this .

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('screenName')}.
```

[image]

Comment: Share your code example for what you have done so far,  show the container component that is in nav stack, the sub-component you are trying to access navigation from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the looks of it, you are taking a misunderstanding of how navigation works! in a react native app's subcomponent system.

If a component is wrapped as a screen in the navigator object while creating it will have direct access to navigation prop!

but if you have sub-component which is inside the render of a component and it is not a screen  ( for sure) then you have to manually pass navigation as a prop to it!

Which in my sense is not a good approach at all! but in your case, it will work

> NOTE : IF I AM CORRECT POST YOUR CODE OF SUBCOMPONENTS! AND I WILL
>   HELP SHOWING THE EXAMPLE

Answer (score 1):

**Get Botttom Tabbar Screen Navigation props**

```
_getScreenProps = () => {
    return (
        {
            navigation: this.props.navigation,
        }
    )
}
```

**Render Tabbar**

```
render() {
    return (
       <View style={{ flex: 1.0 }}>
            <Stack screenProps={this._getScreenProps()} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

On Tab screen use navigation as follow

```
onPress={() => this.props.screenProps.navigation.navigate('screenName')}.
```

**Tabbar**

```
const TabView = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    Contacts: {
        screen: Contacts,
    },
    Group: {
        screen: Group,
    },
    Task: {
        screen: Task,
    },
    Event: {
        screen: EventView
    }
},
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            defaultProps: navigation,
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let iconName;
                let title = ''
                if (routeName === 'Home') {
                    iconName = 'ic_home'
                    title = "HOME"
                } else if (routeName === 'Contacts') {
                    iconName = 'ic_user_home'
                    title = "CONTACTS"
                } else if (routeName === 'Group') {
                    iconName = 'ic_group'
                    title = "PROSPECTS"
                } else if (routeName === 'Task') {
                    iconName = 'ic_document'
                    title = "TASKS"
                } else if (routeName === 'Event') {
                    iconName = 'ic_calculator'
                    title = "EVENTS"
                }


                if (focused) {
                    return (
                        <LinearGradient style={{ flex: 1.0, width: '100%' }}
                            colors={[Constant.COLOR.grediantTop, Constant.COLOR.grediantBottom]}>
                            <View style={{ flex: 1.0, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                                <Image
                                    style={{
                                        height: 25,
                                        width: 25,
                                        tintColor: 'white',
                                        alignSelf: 'center'
                                    }}
                                    tintColor='white'
                                    source={{ uri: iconName }}
                                    resizeMode='contain' />
                                <SPText
                                    style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 2, textAlign: 'center' }}
                                    fontSize={8}
                                    textColor='white'
                                    text={title} />
                            </View>
                        </LinearGradient>
                    )
                }
                else {
                    return (
                        <View style={{ flex: 1.0, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                            <Image
                                style={{
                                    height: 25,
                                    width: 25,
                                    alignSelf: 'center'
                                }}
                                source={{ uri: iconName }}
                                resizeMode='contain' />
                            <SPText
                                style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 2 }}
                                fontSize={8}
                                textColor='gray'
                                text={title} />
                        </View>
                    )
                }


            },
            tabBarOnPress: () => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                navigation.navigate(routeName)
            },

        }),
        tabBarOptions: {
            showLabel: false,
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white',
        },
    })


const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        TabView: {
            screen: TabView,
        },
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        headerMode: 'none',
    }
);


const Stack = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it manually like that:
bring the navigation into the first child like that
const { item, navigation } = props;

inside this child send it into another child (with this name >> ProductCard) like that
<ProductCard {...item} navigation={navigation}/>

or like that if you want to associate with other things

<ProductCard {...item} navigation={navigation} item={item} />

I hope it helps